# Como sobrescrever um metodo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ola eu quero sobrescrever um metodo,
aqui está o codigo da classe folha:

```
from Aluno import *

class Bolsista(Aluno):
    __bolsa = 0.0

    def renovarBolsa(self):
        print(f"Renovando bolsa de {self._nome}")

    def pagarMensalidade(self):
        print(f"{self._nome} é bolsista! Pagamento facilitado")

    def getBolsa(self):
        return self.__bolsa

    def setBolsa(self,bolsa):
        self.__bolsa = bolsa
```

é a sub classe:

```
from Pessoa import *

class Aluno(Pessoa):
    __matricula = 0
    __curso = 'null'

    def pagarMensalidade(self):
        print(f"Pagando mensalidade do aluno {self._nome}")

    def getMatricula(self):
        return self.__matricula

    def setMatricula(self,matricula):
        self.__matricula = matricula

    def getCurso(self):
        return self.__curso

    def setCurso(self,curso):
        self.__curso = curso
```

A classe mãe:

```
class Pessoa():
    _nome = 'null'
    _idade = 0
    _sexo = 'null'

    def fazerAniversario(self):
        self._idade += 1

    def getNome(self):
        return self._nome

    def setNome(self,nome):
        self._nome = nome

    def getIdade(self):
        return self._idade

    def setIdade(self,idade):
        self._idade = idade

    def getSexo(self):
        return self._sexo

    def setSexo(self,sexo):
        self._sexo = sexo

    def toString(self):
        return f"""Dados[nome="{self._nome}", idade="{self._idade}", sexo="{self._sexo}"]"""
```

O codigo Pricipal:

```
b1 = Bolsista()
b1.setMatricula(1112)
b1.setNome("Jubileu")
b1.setBolsa(12.5)
b1.setSexo("M")
b1.pagarMensalidade()
```

quando executo

```
Pagando mensalidade do aluno Cláudio
Jubileu é bolsista! Pagamento facilitado
```

apareceu a mensagem que devia ser sobrescrevida mas por que
isso não aconteceu

Obrigado pela ateção

Comment: É um *warning* do compilador? Coloque mais informações do que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar as anotações @property para "get", @nome_do_atributo.setter para "setter" e o **str** para o "toString". Para sobrescrever o método você deveria utilizar herança (como visto já é utilizado) e a partir do conceito de polimorfismo realizar o desejado.

Se eu fizesse um projeto semelhante faria da seguinte forma:

```
# =============================================================================
# CLASS'S
# =============================================================================

class Pessoa():

    def __init__(self, nome, idade, sexo):

        self._nome = nome
        self._idade = idade
        self._sexo = sexo

        self._check()

    def _check(self):

        if isinstance(self._nome, str) == False:
            message = f"O nome deve possuir retorno {type(str())}"
            raise ValueError(message)

        elif isinstance(self._idade, int) == False:
            message = f"A idade deve possuir retorno {type(int())}"
            raise ValueError(message)

        elif isinstance(self._sexo, str) == False:
            message = f"O sexo deve possuir retorno {type(str())}"
            raise ValueError(message)

        elif self._sexo not in ["M","F"]:
            message = f"O sexo deve ser passado na forma como: (M) masculino ou (F) feminino"
            raise ValueError(message)

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, nome):
        self._nome = nome

    @property
    def idade(self):
        return self._idade

    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, idade):
        self._idade = idade

    @property
    def sexo(self):
        return self._sexo

    @sexo.setter
    def sexo(self, sexo):
        self._sexo = sexo

    def fazerAniversario(self):
        self._idade += 1

    def __str__(self):
        CABECALHO = "\n***********************************\n"
        NOME = f"\n\nNOME: {self._nome}"
        IDADE = f"\nIDADE: {self._idade} ano(s)"
        if(self._sexo == "M"):
            SEXO = f"\nSEXO: ({self._sexo}) - masculino"
        else:
            SEXO = f"\nSEXO: ({self._sexo}) - feminino"
        message = CABECALHO + f"DADOS - PESSOA:" + NOME + IDADE + SEXO + CABECALHO
        return message

class Aluno(Pessoa):

    def __init__(self,matricula, curso, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._matricula = matricula
        self._curso = curso

        self._check_aluno()

    def _check_aluno(self):

        if isinstance(self._matricula, str) == False:
            message = f"A matrícula deve possuir retorno {type(str())}"
            raise ValueError(message)

        elif isinstance(self._curso, str) == False:
            message = f"O curso deve possuir retorno {type(str())}"
            raise ValueError(message)

    @property
    def matricula(self):
        return self._matricula

    @matricula.setter
    def sexo(self, matricula):
        self._matricula = matricula

    @property
    def curso(self):
        return self._curso

    @curso.setter
    def curso(self, curso):
        self._curso = curso

    def pagarMensalidade(self):
        nome = self.nome
        message = f"Pagando mensalidade do aluno: {nome}"
        print(message)

    def __str__(self):
        CABECALHO = "\n***********************************\n"
        NOME = f"\n\nNOME: {self._nome}"
        IDADE = f"\nIDADE: {self._idade} ano(s)"
        if(self._sexo == "M"):
            SEXO = f"\nSEXO: ({self._sexo}) - masculino"
        else:
            SEXO = f"\nSEXO: ({self._sexo}) - feminino"
        CURSO = f"\nCURSO: {self._curso}"
        MATRICULA = f"\nMATRÍCULA: {self._matricula}"
        message = CABECALHO + f"DADOS - ALUNO:" + NOME + IDADE + SEXO + MATRICULA + CURSO + CABECALHO
        return message

class Bolsista(Aluno):

    def __init__(self, bolsa, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._bolsa = bolsa

    def _check_bolsista(self):

        if isinstance(self._bolsa, float) == False:
            message = f"O valor da bolsa deve possuir retorno {type(float())}"
            raise ValueError(message)

    def renovarBolsa(self):
        print(f"Renovando bolsa de {self._nome}")

    def pagarMensalidade(self):
        print(f"{self._nome} é bolsista! Pagamento facilitado")

    @property
    def bolsa(self):
        return self._bolsa

    @bolsa.setter
    def bolsa(self, bolsa):
        self._bolsa = bolsa

    def __str__(self):
        CABECALHO = "\n***********************************\n"
        NOME = f"\n\nNOME: {self._nome}"
        IDADE = f"\nIDADE: {self._idade} ano(s)"
        if(self._sexo == "M"):
            SEXO = f"\nSEXO: ({self._sexo}) - masculino"
        else:
            SEXO = f"\nSEXO: ({self._sexo}) - feminino"
        CURSO = f"\nCURSO: {self._curso}"
        MATRICULA = f"\nMATRÍCULA: {self._matricula}"
        BOLSA = f"\nVALOR BOLSA: R$ {self._bolsa}"
        message = CABECALHO + f"DADOS - ALUNO:" + NOME + IDADE + SEXO + MATRICULA + CURSO + BOLSA + CABECALHO
        return message

# =============================================================================
# MAIN
# =============================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bolsista = Bolsista(12.5, matricula="1612130075", curso="CCO", nome="Fulano", idade=21, sexo="M")

    print(bolsista)

    bolsista.pagarMensalidade()
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não contou tudo pra gente - onde é criado o aluno "Cláudio" ?
Esse código tem problemas, mas deveria imprimir só a informação sobre o aluno "Jubileu" - você deve estar chamando o `.pagarMensalidade`  do Cláudio também, em outro trecho.

Outra dica  - O motivo de Python não ter métodos e atributos privados na linguagem é por que se descobriu com código OOP na prática, que esses conceitos são um pouco de preciosismo, nem tão necessário na grande parte dos casos. Por isso a convenção de um atributo com "_" ser privado, e isso ser só uma convenção - nesse código não tem Nada que justifique você ter esse monte de getters e setters só pra mudar o atributo diretamente. Nenhuma verificação do valor passado, modificação do valor retornado, validação do ator que está excetudando a mudança, *nada*. E se houvesse, a forma mais correta de fazer isso em Python é usando `@property`, nao criando um monte de getters e setters.

Agora, isso é sobre os atributos com um `_` de prefixo. Os atributos com dois `__`  de prefixo, ativam um mecanismo na linguagem de "Name Mangling"  - e vão na verdade causar funcionamento errático do seu programa. Descosidere qualquer documentação que descreva o prefixo `__` como sendo de "atributos privados`: não existem atributos privados em Python - no passado, há mais de 10 anos, havia a tendência de tentar "traduzir" esses conceitos para o mecanismo de name-mangling do Python - mas isso nao traz benefício algum para seu programa ou sua lógica.

Outra coisa que você deve evitar é o `import *` - isso faz com que nem uma pessoa lendo seu código nem sua IDE saibam de onde é que vem os nomes de classes e funções que você usa no seu código. Use sempre o import explícito - se for usar muita coisa de um módulo, prefira importar o módulo e digitar  o `modulo.XXXXX` no codigo do que fazer `from modulo import *` .